# Hot to get search parameters as an object from a url containing hash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, url, url-routing

So I have a url with this format:

```
https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"
```

I know how to get the query strings for a normal url but I was not able to get query strings which come after `#`

I using [node-url](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-url#readme) and I did this so far :

```
import * as urlTool from 'url'
const url = `https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"`
const parsedUrl = urlTool.parse(url, true)
const { pathName, hash } = parsedUrl
```

So up to now, my `hash` have this value `#register?param1="122"&param2="333"` but how can I get the query strings in a dynamic way? The query strings may, or may not be there all the time, and I don't know the name of them as well, how can I get any query strings which may be come after the `#` in a url?

Comment: Can't you just split on the `?` and use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)? Any reference of `?` in a URL signifies query parameters, so you won't have to worry about the structure of the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [SearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

```js
var url = `https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"`;
console.log(new URL(`https://1.com?${url.split("?")[1]}`).searchParams.get("param1"));
```

Building an object using [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var url = `https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"`;
console.log(url.split("?")[1].split("&").reduce(function(result, param) {
  var [key, value] = param.split("=");
  result[key] = value;
  return result;
}, {}));
```

Thought it would be safer to write something like this:

```js
function getParamsAfterHash(url) {
  if (typeof url !== "string" || !url) url = location.href;
  url = url.split("#")[1];
  if (!url) return {};
  url = url.split("?")[1];
  if (!url) return {};
  return url.split("&").reduce(function(result, param) {
    var [key, value] = param.split("=");
    result[key] = value;
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getParamsAfterHash(`https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"`));
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could get a URLSearchParams object directly from a URL object.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a `split` and `Object.fromEntries` with `URLSearchParams` to extract the query parameters into an object:

```js
const url = `https://my-app.com/my-route/someOtherRoute#register?param1="122"&param2="333"`

const [hash, query] = url.split('#')[1].split('?')
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(query))

console.log(hash)
console.log(params)
```